# visible binding not working properly

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I am currently working on a project where I want a button to register the number of clicks and show a message when the user clicks on the button first time. Here is what the code looks like.  Please help me with the code!

HTML:

```
 <div class='liveExample'> 

 <div>Correct Answer <span data-bind='text: numberOfClicks'>&nbsp;</span> </div>

 <div>Wrong Answer <span data-bind='text: numberOfClicks'>&nbsp;</span> </div>

 <button data-bind='click: registerClick'>Click me</button>

 <div data-bind='visible: wantsExplanation'>
     That's too many clicks! Please stop before you wear out your fingers.</div>    
 </div>

 </div>
```

Javascript:

```
var ClickCounterViewModel = function() {
    this.numberOfClicks = ko.observable(0);
    this.wantsExplanation = ko.observable (true);

    this.registerClick = function() {
        this.numberOfClicks(this.numberOfClicks() + 1);
    };

};

ko.applyBindings(new ClickCounterViewModel());
```

css:

```
body { font-family: arial; font-size: 14px; }
.liveExample 
{ 
    padding: 1em; 
    background-color: #EEEEDD; 
    border: 1px solid #CCC; 
    max-width: 655px; 
}
.liveExample input { font-family: Arial; }
.liveExample b { font-weight: bold; }
.liveExample p { margin-top: 0.9em; margin-bottom: 0.9em; }
.liveExample select[multiple] { width: 100%; height: 8em; }
.liveExample h2 { margin-top: 0.4em; }
```

Comment: How is it not working properly?  Where are you changing the value of `wantsExplanation`?

Comment: I was not able to bind the text with the button.

Comment: Done that still not working. Here is the JS fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/3Lqsx/

Comment: Your fiddle works fine. Just make sure your script is at the bottom of the page after all the html elements.

Comment: Sorry for posting the wrong fiddle. Here is the corrected one and it is not working: http://jsfiddle.net/bUdTb/

Comment: You have not included knockoutjs in that jsfiddle, so of course it isnt going to work!

Comment: Tim, even if I do that it still visible binding is not working properly.

Comment: added use of the wantsExplanation variable so the visible binding works : http://jsfiddle.net/bUdTb/1/

Answer (score 0):

You should call the applyBindings only after the document is ready

```
var ClickCounterViewModel = function() {
    this.numberOfClicks = ko.observable(0);
    this.wantsExplanation = ko.observable (true);

    this.registerClick = function() {
        this.numberOfClicks(this.numberOfClicks() + 1);
    };

};

$(document).ready(function() {
     ko.applyBindings(new ClickCounterViewModel());
});
```

Comment: jQuery is not required for knockoutjs

Comment: it's either you use jQuery for document.ready or put the applybindings at the bottom of the page for all the DOM elements to be rendered : https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/knockoutjs/AfYjOocB95E , IMHO the first is cleaner and allows to avoid issues later on.